# Polymorphic Associations in Doctrine?

Tags: doctrine, polymorphic-associations

Is there an equivalent to Rails-like polymorphic associations in Doctrine? I'm trying to do something similar to: http://railscasts.com/episodes/154-polymorphic-association

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, sort of. Inheritance. I am currently using concrete and column aggregation on a project at work, but it's not as powerful as polymorphic associations.

More info [here](http://www.doctrine-project.org/documentation/manual/1_2/en/inheritance).